# JS: what happens if to return a new Promise inside a callback of a then-statement

Tags: javascript, promise

While messing with JavaScript Promises, I noticed a strange thing: if to return a new Promise inside a callback of a then-statement, such a then-statement seems to pass to the next "then" NOT this new Promise, but the result of the latter being resolved! An example:

```
new Promise(resolve => { resolve() })
.then(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(1);
        }, 1000);
    })
})
.then(x => {
    console.log(typeof x, x);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(2);
        }, 1000);
    })
})
.then(x => {
    console.log(typeof x, x);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(3);
        }, 1000);
    })
})
.then(x => {
    console.log(typeof x, x);
})
```

What I get in the console after this, is:

```
number 1
number 2
number 3
```

, which is definitely NOT what I expected, as I know that a then-statement's callbacks should accept a return value of a previous then statement's callback – so I expected to see in the console objects (Promises) instead of numbers... Did I miss something?

Comment: _"If a handler function: ... returns another **pending** promise object, the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by `then` will be subsequent to the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by the handler. Also, the resolved value of the promise returned by `then` will be the same as the resolved value of the promise returned by the handler."_ (Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value))

Comment: To rephrase the blurb Andreas posted from MDN promises cannot **nest**, they automatically flatten. Promise(Promise(foo)) is the same as just Promise(foo). This was actually a fairly controversial decision at the time with a lengthy [github thread](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec/issues/94) argument about monads, but the people driving the A+ spec pushed for and got the current behavior.

Comment: This is the [central point of promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572). Only chaining makes them so useful.

Comment: @JaredSmith It's still controversial :-) And noone on that thread argued that `then` shouldn't unnest, algebraic structure supporters argue that it shouldn't unnest *recursively*.

Comment: @Bergi yes I remember now that you were one of the people specifically in that thread right?

Comment: @Bergi, what is the promise returned by then() and what is the promise returned by the handler? I don't understand the in the text "returns another pending promise object, the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by then will be subsequent to the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by the handler. Also, the resolved value of the promise returned by then will be the same as the resolved value of the promise returned by the handler. "

Comment: @Andreas, I don't know who can answer my question, please.

Comment: @DanielTinajeroDíaz In `a = somePromise.then(() => { …; return b; })`, `a` is the promise returned by `.then()` whereas `b` is the promise returned by the `then` handler.

Comment: great @Bergi, thank you very much, now I understand MDN's statement.

Comment: hi @Bergi +1 - "*In `a = somePromise.then(() => { …; return b; })`, `a` is the promise returned by `.then()` whereas `b` is the promise returned by the `then` handler*" - so, the promise `a` is **fulfilled** with the same value as promise `b` or **rejected** with the same reason as `b`, right?

Comment: @Coder23 yes, see the answer below

Comment: thanks @Bergi +1, yes I saw them, but as always it is always good to know an opinion **more** from a referent in promises.

Comment: in fact, all the answers are great, they already have all 3 of them my +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### [`Promise.prototype.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)
>
> The `then()` method returns a
> [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
> It takes up to two arguments: callback functions for the success and
> failure cases of the `Promise`.
>
> ...
>
> #### Return value
>
> Once a `Promise` is fulfilled or rejected, the respective handler
> function (`onFulfilled` or `onRejected`) will be called asynchronously
> (scheduled in the current thread loop). The behavior of the handler
> function follows a specific set of rules. If a handler function:
>
> - returns a value, the promise returned by `then` gets resolved with the returned value as its value.
> - doesn't return anything, the promise returned by `then` gets resolved with an `undefined` value.
> - throws an error, the promise returned by `then` gets rejected with the thrown error as its value.
> - returns an already fulfilled promise, the promise returned by `then` gets fulfilled with that promise's value as its value.
> - returns an already rejected promise, the promise returned by `then` gets rejected with that promise's value as its value.
> - **returns another pending promise object, the resolution/rejection of the promise returned by `then` will be subsequent to the
>   resolution/rejection of the promise returned by the handler. Also, the
>   resolved value of the promise returned by `then` will be the same as
>   the resolved value of the promise returned by the handler.**

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

The last (bold) bullet point is the answer to your question

Comment: Thanks again, you've helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

When you return something from a callback function of `.then()` method, if that return value is a non-promise value, then it is implicitly wrapped in a promise and then the promise returned by that `.then()` method is fulfilled with that non-promise value.

On the other hand, if the return value of the callback function is itself a promise, then the promise returned by the `.then()` method gets *resolved* to the promise returned by the callback function. This means that the fate of the promise returned by the `.then()` method now depends on whatever happens to the promise returned by the callback function.

**Example:** Assume that the promise returned by the `.then()` method is `promiseThen` and the promise returned by the callback function is `promiseCallback`. Now, if the `promiseCallback` is fulfilled, then the `promiseThen` will also fulfill with the value with which `promiseCallback` fulfilled and this value is what will be passed to the next `.then()` method, if there is one. Similarly, if `promiseCallback` is rejected, then `promiseThen` will also get rejected.

Comment: thanks +1 @Yousaf - the example (the last paragraph) of the best I have seen in StackOverFlow of this case

Answer (score 2):

In your code, there is a promise chain. Please refer https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

In a promise chain, execution of promise `then` callbacks takes place one after another.

i.e Second promise callback is not executed until the first promise callback execution is completed(first promise enters resolved state). Similarly it goes down till the last promise callback in the execution chain.

If any one of the promise callbacks in a promise chain is failed (promise enters rejected state), then the promise callback execution stops there.

i.e. Second promise callback will not be executed if first promise callback fails

**To answer your question**

This article gives an in-depth view of Promise similar to your question
https://codeburst.io/playing-with-javascript-promises-a-comprehensive-approach-25ab752c78c3

You returned a promise object inside the first then callback. So, the next then (second then) callback will not be executed until the promise returned by first then callback enters resolved state or completes execution

Comment: Promises are not executed. Functions (that return promises) can be.

Comment: @Bergi It is for easy understanding. I can't find a good word other than execute to describe. Eg: Promises are executed asynchronously

Comment: But that's wrong. Just be precise about what is actually executed: "*Promise `then` callbacks are executed asynchronously*".

Comment: This answer is much more helpful and easier to understand than the excerpt on mdn mentioned in the topmost voted answer.

Comment: thanks @Anand Raj +1 - *If any one of the promise callbacks in a promise chain is failed (promise enters rejected state), then the **promise callback execution stops there**.* this is worth gold